# Does URL rewriting stop use of CNAME subdomains?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all http requests from example.com to www.example.com.

I am using the .htaccess code below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2 questions:

1. Will this approach prevent me from using subdomains (e.g. cdn.example.com to map to cloudflare or support.example.com to map to zendesk)? If not, please explain why / what the approach actually achieves.
2. If it's working, why does the browser URL not update to show www.example.com when example.com is visited?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It shouldn't prevent you from being able to use other subdomains, 'cause those must be set up on the DNS level and should never hit your Apache server, in general.
2. It should work. Make sure your `mod_rewrite` is enabled and [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to `All` in your Apache config.

Another rule you could try is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way you will only rewrite non-subdomained requests to `www.example.com`.